# How to remove Duplicate record from Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created an SQL query to get records who have events in the next 5 days:

```sql
SELECT Id
,Opportunity_key__c
,Name 
,Primary_Contact_Email__c
,Primary_Contact_Id__c
,Event_Start_Date__c
,Event_End_Date__c  
FROM 
Opportunity_Salesforce
WHERE 
Event_Start_Date__c IS NOT NULL 
AND 
Event_Start_Date__c=convert(date, getDate()+6)
AND 
RecordTypeId='0128b000000xlPIAAY'
```

Opportunity_key__c key is the primary key in a data extension

but showing an error when using append or update

**Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key.**

But when used overite it will work but in the journey enter again so we want only to run at a once.

We set the journey in re-entry mode because our subscriber key contact id

our use case:

If we have an opportunity that has the same email for the same event name, and the same date then only send the email 1 time

If we have an opportunity that has the same email for the same event name, and the different date then send the email again

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to avoid this error by using ID as the primary key in the data extension.